# Django How do I edit posts?

Tags: python, django

I use to code with flash and recently change to Django. I just start Django and having trouble with editing post. This is the code below.

When I edit the post and press submit, it redirect to the post detail page but the post isn't changed.

post_form.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
        <form action="/blog/{{ blog_post.pk }}/update", method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type='text' name='title' value='{{ blog_post.title }}'/>
            <input type='text' class='textinput' name='content' value='{{ blog_post.content }}'/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', index),
    path('blog/<pk>', post_detail),
    path('blog/<pk>/edit', postEdit),
    path('blog/<pk>/update', postUpdate)
]
```

veiws.py

```
def postEdit(request, pk):
    blog_post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_form.html', {'blog_post':blog_post})

def postUpdate(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        blog_post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
        blog_post.title = request.POST.get('title')
        blog_post.content = request.POST.get('content')
        blog_post.save

    return redirect(f'/blog/{pk}')
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `blog_post.save()`

Comment: @KlausD.omg.... Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put () after save.
save() not save!